# Ignore existed table when update-database?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity framework 5 code first in an Asp.Net MVC app. The app already created a table `UserProfile`. I moved the class in a different `DbContext` and also create some new classes for the DbContext; then I ran `enabled-migration`, `add-migration` and `update-database`. I got the following error when `update-database`.

> There is already an object named 'UserProfile' in the database.

How to let EF-code-first don't generate the creating script for the table? However, I will need EF-code first to track the added columns in the class and update the table later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Update-Database -Script` for update a database manually. And you can exclude `'UserProfile'` from resulting script.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question is it?